# Searchview filter not working after I hit the space key

Tags: android

I don't know what happens but my searchView not working well when I input a 2 words value in search bar.

for example:

my  listview displayed like this

> You save me
>
> Above All
>
> I am not ashamed

In searchbar I want to search the song "You save me" with the keyword of "You". The result was fine and displayed the exact match but when I am trying to input the "You save" keyword the result doesn't appear anything in listview. It seems that searchview doesn't work when the inputted value has space between 2 words.

how can I fix this problem?

```
 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, guys. This post is very old but seems that no more has interested to answers my question, so I decided to answer my old question in case someone has the same issue as mine.

**Very important:** Use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView` for better performance.

Create `Recyclerview adapter` and implement this class `Filterable` to your adapter.

then add this code.

```
 @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                final String text = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
                List<SongsEntity> list;
                if (text.isEmpty()) {
                    list = entitySongs; //"entitySongs" is your original arraylist
                }else {
                    List<SongsEntity> songlist = new ArrayList<>();


                    for (SongsEntity song : entitySongs) {
                         if ((song.getTitle().toLowerCase().trim().contains(text))) 
                         {
                             songlist.add(new SongsEntity(song.getId(), song.getTitle(), song.getArtist(),song.getLyrics()));
                          }
                    }

                    list = songlist;
                }

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                results.values = list;

                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                songFiltered = (List<SongsEntity>) filterResults.values; // //"songFiltered" is your filtered arraylist
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

I don't remember the exact cause of that issue but I fixed that issue with this code above.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
searchView.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                                      KeyEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    addTextChangeListener();
```

now create this method

```
    private void addTextChangeListener() {
    searchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence query, int start, int before, int count) {

            query = query.toString().trim().toLowerCase();

            final ArrayList<CityDataModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();



            final CharSequence finalQuery = query;
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // Clear the filter list
                    filteredList.clear();

                    // If there is no search value, then add all original list items to filter list
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(finalQuery)) {

                        filteredList.addAll(cities);

                    } else {
                        // Iterate in the original List and add it to filter list...
                        for (CityDataModel item : cities) {
                            if (item.getCity_name().toLowerCase().contains(finalQuery.toString().toLowerCase())
                                    ) {
                                // Adding Matched items
                                filteredList.add(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Set on UI Thread
                    ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // Notify the List that the DataSet has changed...
                            adapter = new SearchCityAdapter(SearchCityClass.this, filteredList);
                            recyclerSearchCity.setAdapter(adapter);


                            if (filteredList.size() == 0) {
                                tvNoCityFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            } else {
                                tvNoCityFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            }).start();


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it says, cannot resolve method setOnEditorActionListener(anonymous android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener) :-(

Comment: The above ans doesnt work as it is a searchview of android and not the EditText ie. the searchview is not a child of Edittext here.