# Search View shows blank after entering a space - Java

Tags: java, android, searchview

Search View shows blank after entering a space.

Duplicate question - [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535177/) , but using recycler view doesn't suit me. Are there other options.

I will be very glad if you help!

I am filtering now:

```
mySearchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args)
{

```
    // Creating a list of Integers
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(3, 4, 6, 12, 20);

    // Getting a stream consisting of the
    // elements that are divisible by 5
    // Using Stream filter(Predicate predicate)
    list.stream()
        .filter(num -> num % 5 == 0)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: call this method in `afterTextChanged`?

Answer (score 0):

You must write your code in onTextChanged.

```
mySearchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            
        }
    });
```